# AwesomeNestedSet, virtual attribute and JSON output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have this model:

```
class MenuItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :name_with_level
  acts_as_nested_set # AwesomeNestedSet gem

  def self.nested_names
    self.each_with_level(MenuItem.order(:lft)) do |menu_item, level|
      name = "- " * level + menu_item.name
      menu_item.name_with_level = name
    end
  end
end
```

Action from controller:

```
def list
  menu_items = MenuItem.all
  render :json => {:items => menu_items}
end
```

How can I include `name_with_level` in the output JSON with one hit to DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this SO answer will help: [Including a virtual attribute in the respond_with hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428852/including-a-virtual-attribute-in-the-respond-with-hash)

In your case:

```
MenuItem

def as_json(options = {})
  super.as_json(options).merge(name_with_level: name_with_level)
end
```

That's the easy way, assuming you want all `menu_items` to return this virtual attribute in the JSON-style representation of themselves. Otherwise, you'd need to build the ruby hash yourself to include `name_with_level` for each `menu+item` and then `.to_json` the whole thing.

Comment: or use own method: as_json(methods: :method_name)